# A possible application of Fubini's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $u \in L^{1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset R^n$ is a bounded domain. For each $k \in R$ let $A_k:= \{ x \in \Omega ; u(x) > k\}$.

Define $f(k):= \int_{A_k}(u(x) - k) dx$. I am reading a book and the author says that

$$f(k)= \int_{k}^{+ \infty} |A_t| \ dt.$$

I am trying to prove this by using Fubini's theorem, but I am getting anywhere.
Please someone could help me to prove the equality or point me a reference ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$u(x)-k = \int_{k}^{u(x)} 1 \, dy = \int_k^{\infty} 1_{\{y<u(x)\}} \, dy = \int_k^{\infty} 1_{A_y}(x) \, dy.$$

Applying Tonelli's theorem yields

$$f(k) = \int_{A_k} \int_k^{\infty} 1_{A_y}(x) \, dy \, dx = \int_k^{\infty} \int_{A_k} 1_{A_y}(x) \, dx \, dy = \int_k^{\infty} \underbrace{|A_k \cap A_y|}_{|A_y|} \, dy$$

where we have used that

$$A_k \cap A_y = A_y \qquad \text{for all} \, \, y \geq k.$$